# What does に do here?

Tags: grammar

> 屋内は外見**に**負けず劣らずの半壊模様。

I feel like the sentence means something like "The inside (of the church) was as equally destroyed as the outside."

But I'm not sure what the に does in this sentence. Could someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hints: From [ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%AB%E8%B2%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%9A%E5%8A%A3%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A), and you can also search from [WWWJDIC examples](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?10)

Comment: @Flaw, none of those have examples where it is followed by の. They're all examples of adverbial use, whereas this is... verbal use? Nominal use? That is to me the interesting question. Tomm, once you know that 外見に負ける means "lose to the outside (appearance)", do you understand the structure of the whole sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「に」 just happens to be the correct particle to use in saying:

> 「～～**に**[勝]{か}つ」 "to win ***against*** ~~"
>
> 「～～**に**[負]{ま}ける」 "to lose ***to*** ~~"

It had no choice but add use 「に」 to the object 「外見」 because the next word is 負けず劣らず, of which the first part comes from 「負ける」.

Your translation is good, by the way.